# Access to session variables to the client

Tags: jsp, session

I am making a web-app in which a user logs in to his account and then can view the details of the other users and can only edit his own details, unless he has been assigned as the admin of the site. This is just the beginning.

But my question is regarding session hijacking. Under session hijacking, if we get the access to the other user's session id i can access his account.
And under my project I am validating the username and password at the log-in, and then storing the username of the user at the session. Something like this;

session.setAttribute("uname",username);

So, my question is: A lot of times we know the usernames of our friends. If I am running my own account, I can see my own session id very easily, so is there any way i can see the session variables set by a site?! 
So, in my case can a user somehow see that i have stored the username on session and by any chance change it?! Just like in session hijacking we alter the session-id.

I am really sorry, I know this is a very confusing question. :|
But please do help someone.. 
Thanks in advance..

Comment: This might help http://balamaci.wordpress.com/2012/05/08/preventing-session-fixation-type-of-attacks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure to use https. Otherwise all security is lost due to the password being sent over the net in plaintext on the login screen.
2. You should also fortify against session hijacking by (at least) storing ip/browser in the session and validating those against the ones coming in the request headers, invalidating the session and redirecting when there's a mismatch.
3. Unless you expose the ability to view and change the session information to the user (i.e. by making a page that allows them to), they shouldn't be able to. Of course if you make such a page and don't secure it properly, then they might be able to find a way to exploit it.